# Predicate failing with UUID's?

Tags: swift, uuid, predicate, swift-data

I have a fairly simple `Categories` class shown at the bottom of the post. `keyValue` is a UUID value, but this predicate is failing.

```
let keyPredicate = #Predicate<Categories> { $0.uuidKey == keyValue }
```

When I use it in a fetch request I get the very uninformative error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (SwiftData.SwiftDataError error 1.)`.

Fetching `var keyDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Categories>()` returns a nice array.

```
let test = try modelContext.fetch(keyDescriptor)
let filterTest = test.filter { 
    $0.uuidKey == keyValue
}
```

`filterTest` returns a very nice filtered array with one `Categories` instance as I expect. Any suggestions why the #Predicate doesn't work aside from this being beta software?

```
@Model
class Categories: Identifiable {
    
    // MARK: Identifiable
    var id: UUID { return uuidKey }
    
     // MARK: - Properties
    @Attribute(.unique) var uuidKey: UUID = UUID()
    // var uuidKey: UUID = UUID()
    var dateCreated: Date = Date()
    var dateModified: Date = Date()
    var dateRealm: Date? = nil
    var uuidUser: UUID = UUID()
    var uuidFamily: UUID = UUID()
    var myName: String = ""
}
```

Xcode Version 15.0 beta (15A5160n)

Comment: Could you show the code where you use the predicate?

Comment: Problem went away in Xcode Version 15.0 beta 2 (15A5161b).